# Помогите пожалуйста. Нужно с помощью ксс сделать так, чтобы картинка обрезалась другим border-radiusom

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

На курсах задали сделать. У меня никак не получается обрезать картинку так чтобы радиус элемента сзади обрезал картинку спереди как на картинке. Так-же не получается вставить круг внизу. Как это возможно сделать? Подскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А есть такие курсы где учат как правильно задавать вопросы на stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1):

Все я разобрался к картикне нужно было добавить
clip-path: inset(0 round 35px 35px 0 0);